# Using asyncio and aiohttp in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

To better familiarize with async requests I wrote a very simple scraper that relies on [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) to retrieve some basic information from the product page (product name and availability status) or an Italian e-commerce retailer.
Code is organized according the following structure:

### `stores.py`

`stores` module contains a prototype `AsyncScraper` that basically holds all request-related methods: takes care of building the coroutine task list (one coroutine each product to be scraped) plus a method to dispatch the request and extract target information.

Given each website has different DOMs, each e-commerce website will have its own class implementing specific extraction methods.

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio.tasks import wait_for

from aiohttp.client import ClientSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import const


class AsyncScraper:
    """
    A base scraper class to interact with a website.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.product_ids = None
        self.base_url = None
        self.content = None

    # Placeholder method
    def get_product_title():
        pass

    # Placeholder method
    def get_product_availability():
        pass

    async def _get_tasks(self):
        tasks = []
        async with ClientSession() as s:
            for product in self.product_ids:
                tasks.append(wait_for(self._scrape_elem(product, s), 20))
            print(tasks)
            return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    async def _scrape_elem(self, product, session):
        async with session.get(
            self._build_url(product), raise_for_status=True
        ) as res:

            if res.status != 200:
                print(f"something went wrong: {res.status}")

            page_content = await res.text()
            self.content = BeautifulSoup(page_content, "html.parser")

            # Extract product attributes
            title = self.get_product_title()
            availability = self.get_product_availability()

            # Check if stuff is actually working
            print(f"{title} - {availability}")

    def scrape_stuff(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self._get_tasks())

    def _build_url(self, product_id):
        return f"{self.base_url}{product_id}"


class EuronicsScraper(AsyncScraper):
    """
    Class implementing extractions logic for euronics.it
    """
    base_url = "https://www.euronics.it/"

    def __init__(self):
        self.product_ids = const.euronics_prods

    def get_product_title(self):
        title = self.content.find(
            "h1", {"class": "productDetails__name"}
        ).text.strip()
        return title

    def get_product_availability(self):
        avail_kw = ["prenota", "aggiungi"]
        availability = self.content.find(
            "span", {"class": "button__title--iconTxt"}
        ).text.strip()

        # Availability will be inferred from button text
        if any(word in availability.lower() for word in avail_kw):
            availability = "Disponibile"
        else:
            availability = "Non disponibile"

        return availability
```

### `const.py`

Target products to be scraped are stored in a `const` module. This is as simple as declaring a set of product IDs.

```py
# Products ids to be scraped
euronics_prods = (
    "obiettivi-zoom/nikon/50mm-f12-nikkor/eProd162017152/",
    "tostapane-tostiere/ariete/155/eProd172015168/",
)
```

### `runner.py`

The script is ultimately run by iterating over a list of scrapers and invoking their `scrape_stuff` method, inherited from the `AsyncScraper` parent class.

```py
"""
This is just a helper used as a script runner
"""
from stores import EuronicsScraper


def main():
    scrapers = [EuronicsScraper()]

    for scraper in scrapers:
        scraper.scrape_stuff()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Questions

I am mainly interested if I've overlooked anything major that might get this piece of code hard to rework or to debug in the future. While I was writing it, it made complete sense to me as:

- Implementing a new scraper is just a matter of subclassing `AsyncScraper` and implementing extractions methods.
- All request-related logic is in one place. It might be necessary to override these methods for classes dealing with websites that need some js interaction (probably using an headless browser using [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/)) but I feel it's  way beyond the scope of this review.

One thing I am not too fond of (probably need to dive deeper into inheritance) is the use of placeholder methods in `AsyncScraper` as it'll force me to implement *n* dummy methods (where *n* is the number of website-specific methods that can be found in the other classes). I feel this is a bit of a hack and kind of defeats the purpose of class inheritance.

Any advice is more than welcome.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I am not too fond of (probably need to dive deeper into
> inheritance) is the use of placeholder methods in AsyncScraper as
> it'll force me to implement n dummy methods (where n is the number of
> website-specific methods that can be found in the other classes). I
> feel this is a bit of a hack and kind of defeats the purpose of class
> inheritance.

Instead of additional placeholder methods in `AsyncScraper`, you could use a single abstract method that returns a `dict` of additional site-specific data. Then concrete classes would override the single abstract method for the *n* additional data points. Something like:

**stores.py**

```py
class AsyncScraper:
...

    def get_site_specific_details() -> dict[str, str]:
        raise NotImplementedError() # or pass if this is optional

...

    async def _scrape_elem(self, product, session):
    
    ...

      # Extract product attributes
      title = self.get_product_title()
      availability = self.get_product_availability()
      additional_details = get_site_specific_details()

      # Check if stuff is actually working
      print(f"{title} - {availability}")
      print("Additional details: ")
      for name, value in additional_details.items():
          print(f"{name}: {value}")

      ...

class SomeNewScraper(AsyncScraper):

...
    
   def get_site_specific_details() -> dict[str, str]:
      details = {}
      positive_reviews = self.content.find("...")
      details["positive_reviews"] = positive_reviews
      
      ...
  
      return details
```

Then `AsyncScraper` can focus on the minimum set of attributes required across all site scrapers.

**Note**: Python does have an [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) lib, but I'm not familiar with it. My example probably isn't using the best syntax, but conceptually I think it gets the point across.

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to give it some thought, this looks like a step in the right direction - will definitely play around with it.

Comment: Post what you come up with... I like to learn new approaches.

Comment: I've implemented your approach and I believe it serves the purpose well. Obv it forces to be careful with helper methods to avoid ending up with a too long `get_site_specific_details` (but again, it is minor).